# WebRTC audio only activates on voice

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, mediastream

I'm sending audio from getUserMedia over a WebRTC MediaStream. I want to send all types of audio data, not just voices. My problem is that the audio cuts out if there are no voices even if there is some background noise that the microphone picks up. I thought the problem was with the voiceActivityDetection parameter when creating the offer, however even when I disable it the problem persists. How should I go about sending the essentially raw audio data over a MediaStream without the voice processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, when these APIs were designed, they were built with a lot of processing enabled by default.  Fortunately, they can be disabled with your `getUserMedia` audio constraints:

```
autoGainControl: false,
echoCancellation: false,
noiseSuppression: false
```

This will greatly improve your audio quality.  Note however that the whole WebRTC stack will still have effects on your audio.  A WebRTC call is optimized for realtime voice communication.  Audio is constantly adjusted in speed to keep to as realtime as possible.  Comfort noise is often added (and can be disabled by munging your SDP).  Audio bitrates are often set very low (also adjustable via SDP).  If audio quality matters to you (such as for music), WebRTC probably isn't the best choice.  Consider MediaRecorder instead.

Comment: could you please help me with this? => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894967/how-to-use-sdptransform-in-peer-js