# How to use sdpTransform in Peer.js?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs, sdp, opus

I am developing a voice call app for android using peer.js. It is working but there is a lag in audio (around 1-5 seconds). So I was searching for a fix and found out that I can enable `DTX Audio` to reduce the number of packets sent. But I have no idea How to access and change `SDP` object in peer.js. Here is my code,

```
let audioConstraints = {
    channelCount: 1,
    sampleRate: 16000,
    sampleSize: 8,
    volume: 1,
    latency: 0.003,
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    autoGainControl: true,
  };

constraints = { audio: audioConstraints, video: false };

let localStream;
//listen for calls
function listen() {
  peer.on("call", (call) => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function (stream) {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        localStream = stream;
        call.answer(stream);
        call.on("stream", (remoteStream) => {
          Android.onPeerStream();
          remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        Android.logEvent("getUserMedia error: " + err);
      });
  });
}

//start call
function startCall(otherUserId) {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function (stream) {
      localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      localStream = stream;
      const call = peer.call(otherUserId, stream);
      call.on("stream", (remoteStream) => {
        Android.onPeerStream();
        remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
      });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      Android.logEvent("getUserMedia error: " + err);
    });
}
```

could someone please share a working example of how to access and modify SDP in peer.js? Also, how can I tune the `audioConstraints` to achieve low network lag while keeping decent voice quality?

**UPDATE**
Found the way to access SDP in peer.js but still can't figure it out how to enable DTX audio.

Comment: "UPDATE Found the way to access SDP" - could you show how you did that?

Comment: @user2677034 `call.answer()` and `peer.call()` methods have `sdpTransform` argument, which takes a function that, in turn, gets SDP string as an argument and can manage it